# Cell energy consumption and food intake

Tags: metabolism, food, nutrition, bioenergetics

I am wondering if each cell in human body starts consuming ten percent more energy, how much food one has to consume compared to normal intake?

Comment: The answer is relatively simple: About 10% more (assuming that there is not much loss in the uptake and conversion).

Comment: Does efficiency of digestive system play a part? If it is 10% efficient, then consumption should be doubled.

Comment: Compared to IV injection, consumption via the digestive tract gets about 80% of administered drug. So it may be that you would need to multiply that by 1.2 so you get 12% more food intake. But this question really is not physiologically going to ever happen like you phrase it.